# Exponential Growth/ Decay World Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If a city had a population of $2,348$ in 1980 and a population of $1,958$ in 2000, then what year in the future will the population be $<1$?

I found the growth constant, which in this case is decay and it is $-0.0091$ but I am not sure how to do the second part of the question, finding the year in the future etc. Can you please show steps on that part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the main equation is

```
y(t) = y(0)e^-kt   

y(t) = population at time t
y(0) = initial population
```

now since you already have k, you can just sub it back into the equation
but now:

y(0) is 2348

y(t) = 1

k = -0.0091

and solve for t
(the same way as if you were solving for k)

solving for t would look something like this;

ln( y(t)/y(0) ) = -kt

and I think from here you know where to go

Comment: Okay thanks! Would you get 852.89 which rounds to approx. 853 years?

Comment: yes, that is the same answer I got :)